# Is there a way to get the street name from a CLLocation in iOS?

Tags: ios

In my app I'd need to know the name of the street the user is in. At the moment I only know hot to get the user location with the `CLLocationManger` object and to show it in a `MKMapView` but I can't find any way to get the name of the street where the user is.

Is there a way to do this with or without the iOS sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From iOS 5 and on, you can do this making use of `CLGeocoder`. I strongly advise you to take a look at the Location Awareness Programming Guide, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html).

In order to get the street, you should make a request using `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:`. In that completion handler you will receive an array of `CLPlacemark` objects. To get the street, just extract the object from the `addressDictionary` dictionary in the CLPlacemark object using the `kABPersonAddressStreetKey` key.

Answer (score 0):

Simple extension:

```
import CoreLocation

typealias StreetNameHandler = (String?) -> Void

extension CLLocation {

    func streetNameWithCompletionBlock(completionBlock: StreetNameHandler) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self) { placemarks, error in

            if let addressDictionary = placemarks?.first?.addressDictionary, street = addressDictionary["Street"] as? String {
                completionBlock(street)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
location.streetNameWithCompletionBlock { street in
    print("street \(street)")
}
```